# Python watchdog get modified lines for monitored file

Tags: python, watchdog

I'm having some trouble reading the contents of a file.

The scenario is a bit tricky, I have two scripts, the first one uses a watchdog (https://pythonhosted.org/watchdog/_modules/watchdog/) to monitor a file called `'table.csv'` the second script at specific intervals appends new data to `'table.csv'`.

I'm experiencing the following problem: when I start the watchdog, I get the initial contents of the file, but then when I add some other data from my other script, the watchdog detects the modification to the file, but the file descriptor in python seems unable to read the "new contents".

What do you think might be the problem?

I have tried opening the file again when the change to it is detected, but at runtime when I open the second time, it seems to be blank, nothing on it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem using.

```
file_descriptor.flush()
```

which is needed to update the file pointers in the os.

Comment: Can you update your code on getting the newly added lines?

Comment: Great question but answer is way to vague. Can U give any explanation at all of what this means? Would be helpful since I have same question.

Comment: @MoteZart each time you add contents in your file, you have to flush or "commit" changes to persistent memory so the other service can actually read what has been just written.
In this case file_descriptor would be
file_descriptor = open("myfile.csv", "rw")